# How do Ruby 1.8 threads behave in Phusion Passenger?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, passenger

If I fire of 1 or 1000 of these in a controller action:

```
Thread.new {
  # do some stuff
}
```

1. Will they indeed run asynchronously with the http request?
2. If an exception is raised, where does it trickle up to?
3. Anything else I should know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads and exceptions are not necessarily friends since exceptions can't bust out of the current thread and alert the parent thread. You also need to turn on thread exception notification or you'll never hear about them at all:

```
Thread.new do
  Thread.abort_on_exception = true
end
```

You'll also need to call `Thread.join` on each new thread or the main one will hurry along without them.

This way your code will at least halt on an exception instead of simply terminating the thread that generated one and continuing on as if nothing had happened.

Make sure that the things you're calling inside your thread are thread safe or you may get unexpected results.

Comment: 1. instead of doing abort_on_exception, i'll just wrap all the code inside in a catching block which reports them (that sound fine?) 2. if I join in my main thread then that will make my controller synchronous again, won't it?

Comment: Reporting the exceptions is better than ignoring them, that's true. As for the second thing, threads will continue to run independently even when you call `Thread.join`, but the main thread will wait for them to all finish before proceeding from that point. That way you don't race on to send the response before the threads have done their work.

Comment: Ah okay. Well in this case I DO want the response to finish before the threads have done their work :-D

Comment: Don't get carried away with threads when what you really want is something like [delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job). Having rogue, unjoined threads is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Agreed. In this case they are doing simple logging tasks... but you are right, there is always a risk. I should set a timeout at least.